# Mathbb font for lowercase letters

Tags: fonts, mathbb

I was wondering how to get the mathbb font in lowercase letters. I found the font but the lowercase letters are math symbols as (f) = (\mho).

So my question is simple, is there a way to get these letters in the latex document

Comment: the ams font is uppercase only, some fonts have lowercase, eg stix2 package

Comment: Please look into `cmathbb.sty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created in Photoshop the font style I wanted to do, applying the blackboard bold font effect on cmmi10 font, instead of using others similars. I wonder if we can combine this font with bb and make it offcial.

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 9):

You just need to use a blackboard bold font that actually has lowercase letters, unlike AMS's blackboard font obtained with `amssymb`. The package `mathalpha` provides several options, which are listed in the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha).

For example, here are the lowercase letters of Libertinus's blackboard bold font, obtained with the option `bb=libus`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bb=libus]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
\(\mathbb{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}\)
\end{document}
```

As another example, here's the result if `bb=libus` is changed to `bb=stix`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! But the mathbb font (Blackboard Bold) gives an outline effect on cmr10 font. I wonder if there's a font that gives these outline for lowercase cmr10 font and upper/lowercase cmmi10 font

Comment: @Agente156 Unfortunately, AMS's blackboard bold font does not have lowercase letters, so (as far as I know) another font must be used to get these symbols.

Answer (score 3):

Open Type fonts (.otf) are accessible via `unicode-math` package (compile with xelatex/lualatex), for example the TexGyre Math fonts. Lower case Latin bb is part of Unicode now.

[image: lowercase latin bb]

Detail

[image: detail]